# Firebase Site - Invalid Dynamic Link

Tags: firebase

I had not setup Dynamic Link on the site, but I had just added a custom domain and connected it to have the SSL.

Today when i tried to access my site, i notice that is append ?_imcp=1 to it and have the following message

Invalid Dynamic Link. Any help?

[image]

Addition some updates. After spending the evening trying to figure out what's wrong.

I am able to do a [www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com) -> redirect to xxx.com. This works perfectly

But if i were to hit xxx.com directly, its append ?_imcp=1 to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is probably a patch solution.

I basically did a redirect of xxx.com to [www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com).

And i did a redirect of [www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com) to xxx.com

This bring up the website. But if anyone have proper solution. Please post here.